# Finding matrix A from eigenvalues and ODE

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation 
$$x'=Ax+\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ e^t \\ 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right), x(0)=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right)$$
which I have solved to get
$$x(t)=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ te^t \\ 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right)$$
using the matrix exponential $\left[\begin{matrix} e^t & 0 & 0 \\ 3te^t & e^t & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e^{2t} \\ \end{matrix}\right]$ calculated from given eigenvectors $w=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right)$, v=$\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right)$ and u=$\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{matrix}\right)$ with eigenvalues $1$, $1$ and $2$ respectively.

How do I use all these things I have calculated to find A?

I assume, by properties of the matrix exponential, that the basic form is something like
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & a & b \\ c & 1 & d \\ e & f & 2 \\ \end{matrix}\right]$$
but other than that I don't really see how to go about it.

I have attempted to use this general form to reconstruct it from the eigenvectors but I have ended up with values that do not work. What other methods can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to obtain $A$ from $e^{tA}$ is
$$
A=\frac{d}{dt}e^{tA}\biggl|_{t=0}.
$$